# background image on border

Tags: css, border, background-image

I've a background image and border on body. I look like this now (on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nokibewi/3)):

[image]

But I want background image stays on border, so background image will be visible completely. How to put background image on border?

**EDIT**

Desired result:
[image]

**EDIT2**
I've already used :after and :before as @Danield offered and it worked. I've 4 corners and I've put 2 of them with :after and :before (so 2 of them are left without corner images). I'm looking another way without pseudo elements. Also not positioned block elements with background. I'm trying to achieve by css.

Answer (score 1):

Add an absolutely positioned pseudo element.

```
body:after{
  content: '';
  display:block;
  background-image: url("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/97adf5e1abeb6454d6c6a6a39b81265a?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG");
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

**[Updated JsBin](http://jsbin.com/nokibewi/11/)**

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe well, I want image will be on top of border, not close or near. I can move right, left with changing position, but it stays underneath of border. I added desired result.

Comment: Great, I've already used `:after` and `:before`. I've 4 corners and I've put 2 of them with :after and :before (so 2 of them are left without corner images). I'm looking another way without pseudo elements.

Comment: @bob - that's the kind of stuff you should include in your question

Answer (score 0):

try this  CSS property to use image on border

```
  border-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/97adf5e1abeb6454d6c6a6a39b81265a?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG) 25% repeat;
```

Comment: It overrides border color. I need to keep both border and background-image

Comment: very interesting thing .. :)